# Why the string is send only once by holding combine keys when I using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

My script is

```
^Numpad0::Send "hello world"
```

When I hold ctrl+Numpad0, it will output "hello world" only once. Then it will output character "0". Just like this:

**hello world0000000000000**

How to output "hello world" repeatedly by holding ctrl+Numpad0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [$ prefix](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) forces the keyboard hook to be used to implement
> this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the Send command from
> triggering it.
> The $ prefix is equivalent to having specified [#UseHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_UseHook.htm) somewhere
> above the definition of this hotkey.

```
$^Numpad0::Send "hello world"
```